# Drawing binary search tree with Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree, cytoscape.js, dagre

I am trying to draw a binary search tree using Cytoscape.js. I am using Dagre layout. In my tree, each node has exactly two children - I am creating nodes with 'null' labels for empty subtrees. My problem is that sometimes the left child is on the right side and vice versa.

How can I set which node should be the left child and which should be the right?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output.
Refer this link on how you could ask a good question
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [dagre documentation](https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre/wiki#configuring-the-layout), the only parameters that look as though they could affect order include:

- The ordering of the nodes and edges in the graph itself.
- The `ranker` option.

If neither one allows specifying order in the resultant dagre layout, then you'll have to file a feature request with [dagre](https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre/issues).  The cytoscape-dagre package is just a wrapper.

Comment: Thanks, neither worked for me, but I decided not to use layout at all and handle positions manually because it's better for my use case.